# Codeigniter - matching user entered password to hashed password stored in DB always returns false. Please help

Tags: php, mysql, oop, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have my controller Setup
my join_model
and my login_model

A user registers and after they have passed all validation and captcha etc and have clicked submit they are set to setup.

My setup controller loads the join_model and the create() method, takes all the post data and gets ready to send it to db. This is when the password they entered in the signup form get's hashed, salted etc.

After this I have an if statement that checks whether user passed the checkLogin method in the login_model with TRUE. This method is in the setup controller and I called it loginValidated.

If that is TRUE then user is re-directed to member area (dash).

When I test I keep getting sent to the failed page. I also changed the if state to (!this->loginValidated()) and then I get de-directed to the account area meaning the passwords must not match.

I was wondering if anyone could have a quick look through my code to see if they spot where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php


class Setup extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('join_model');
        $this->join_model->create();
        if ($this->loginValidated()) { //if user credentials passed validation

        redirect('dash'); //forward to dashboard
        }
        else {
            redirect('failed');
        }
    }
    public function loginValidated() {
        $this->load->model('login_model'); //load login_model model
        $this->login_model->checkLogin(); //load checkLogin method

    }
 }



<?php
//MY CONTROLLER

class Login_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function checkLogin() {
            return Join_Model::$u;

            $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email')); //compare db email to email entered in form
            $this->db->where('password', $u->password); //compare db password to password entered by user after hashing
            $query = $this->db->get('user'); // get the above info from 'user' table

            if ($query->num_rows == 1) { //if number of rows returned is 1

            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$u->id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('username',$u->username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('first_name',$u->first_name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('last_name',$u->last_name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', 'TRUE');

            return TRUE;
      }
   }
}


<?php
// MY JOIN MODEL

class Join_Model extends CI_Model {
    public static $u;
    public function create() {
                $this->load->helper('date');
                $this->load->library('encrypt');

  $u->first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
                $u->last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
                $u->email = $this->input->post('email');

                // sha1 and salt password
                $salt = $this->config->item('encryption_key');
  $password = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password'));
                $start_hash = sha1($salt . $password);
                $end_hash = sha1($password . $salt);
                $hashed = sha1($start_hash . $password . $end_hash);
                $u->password = sha1($hashed);

                $u->birthday = $this->input->post('year') . '-' . $this->input->post('month') . '-' . $this->input->post('day');
                $u->sex = $this->input->post('sex');

                $u->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()); // date and time user joined the website

                $this->db->insert('user', $u);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep a static field containing your user's data in the Login_Model? It would seem to me like that would completely go wrong in a multi-user environment

Comment: In order to be able to use $u variable in the Login_model otherwise I get an undefined variable error.

Comment: yes, but a return means your function won't execute beyond that line :) So even if your validation code was good, it wouldn't run.

Comment: Oh,  still learning but I'm glad. What would be the correct way for me to make variables from one file accessible in another file?

Comment: That would be using objects and fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My CI is a bit rusty, but it looks like you are returning something on the first line of your `checkLogin()` function, it would seem to me that the code below that is not getting executed then.

Also, you need to hash the password again before you send it to the database, otherwise you are comparing the clear text password to the hash.

Also, it seems to me like you'd need a User controller and model, not a model for user registration and login. Furthermore you should refrain from loading libraries inside your model, this is considered ugly when working with an MVC framework.

Comment: The thing is when I check my database the password is stored hashed and I thought because I made $->password equal the hashed password that I wouldn't need to hash it again?

Comment: Nope, you just set a property that was persisted to the database. You could add a hash function to the model that you can then call every time.

Comment: I have a controller for login logout registration .. I just didn't post the code as they aren't in use at this stage.

Comment: Would this be correct?  $this->db->where('password', sha1($hashed)); and some how pass my hashed variable into that method/class?

Comment: I'd recommend adding a convenience method that would do the entire hashing process for you. But you're on track now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hash any user-entered password and then check the hash against the database, not the raw string the user entered.

Comment: All along I thought this was what I was doing. Where would I need to do this?